# Limit jekyll post list to certain categories

Tags: liquid, jekyll

I have a [jekyll](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll) website and I have a category (called `photo`) and I wanted to create a separate layout for a page that would list just the posts that were in the `photo` category. I also want to keep posts with the `photo` category out of the main index page.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I just used an `{% unless %}` block in the main index page to make sure the post wasn't a photo. Example:

```
{% unless post.category == "photo"%}
    {% comment %} List posts... {% endcomment %}
{% endunless %}
```

And I used the same thing for showing *only* photos. Just with an `if` instead of `unless`.

Comment: I cannot find any information on the `unless` tag. Is it still supported?

Comment: @orschiro check the Liquid documentation: https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/wiki/Liquid-for-Designers#tags

Answer (score 34):

All categories are available within the site object, access the posts of a category via `site.categories.photo` so your loop would look like this

```
{% for post in site.categories.photo %}
    # render the photo post html
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Unless I misunderstand the question, this should be the correct answer.

Comment: Indeed. Correct, but a bit late.

Comment: @matb33 I.e. later than a quarter, heh.

Comment: I prefer this solution, but that is just me :)

Comment: @matb33 not the full answer because he will still have the `photo` posts in his main index page

Answer (score 4):

The category is case sensitive as well. If your category is photo then it will look like this:

```
{% for post in site.categories.photo %}
    # render the photo post html
{% endfor %}
```

If your category is Photo then it will look like this:

```
{% for post in site.categories.Photo %}
    # render the photo post html
{% endfor %}
```

Just a quick detail that I tripped up on my build so I thought I would share.